# Adding non refrenced dll in bin folder while publishing website

Tags: visual-studio-2012, publish-profiles

How to write code for copying dll and xml files from one folder to bin while publishing the website.Need to add few dll in published folder automatically which are not referenced in project Need to know the syntax for the same.